# jQuery - read tab data

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML snippet as below

```
 <li class="tab selected" data-tab-id="10">
    <a href="#"></a>
    </li>

  var tabs = $('.tab');
  tabs.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(data-tab-id value here);
});
```

When a tab is selected, 
how can I read the `data-tab-id` value which I need to pass to AJAX to fetch the right data?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var tabs = $('.tab');
   tabs.click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert($(this).attr('data-tab-id')); //gets data-tab-id  attribute... 10
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tabs.click(function(e) {
    e.prevetDefault();
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```